# How to use Nginx with different physical machines?

Tags: networking, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have many VMs running with different web servers and such. I want to be able to use the SSL port on more than one machine, which is where Nginx comes in. I have looked and dug, and I do not understand if you can achieve using **different physical** VMs with Nginx.

I have a:

- CentOS machine running Apache as my main (no virtual hosts configured) website. IP of 10.40.1.12 internally, reachable at kodysalak.com
- Windows Server 2016 with exchange on it. IP of 10.40.1.17 internally, reachable at mail.kodysalak.com
- Windows Server 2016 with Spiceworks' HelpDesk software (Apache). IP of 10.40.1.14 internally, reachable at help.kodysalak.com

Those are the hosts that use 80/443. I have a separate CentOS machine running Nginx with no configuration done with it. IP of 10.40.1.18.

I am **brand new** to nginx and reverse proxy in general, you might have to hold my hand to help me.

Comment: Why do you want a reverse proxy in the first place? I don't see any need for it, as all your services are running on different hosts anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer lies between [this doc](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) and [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/538803/nginx-reverse-ssl-proxy-with-multiple-subdomains).
I hope that you will understand the 3 server sections for kodysalak.com, mail.kodysalak.com and help.kodysalak.com. You need to configure and use their respective internal IPs.

It is not clear if you can set up SSL with nginx, so try [this doc](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html).
You need to create some certificates, even self signed.